# Pure HTML form works, same query with Ajax fails

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-oauth, passport.js

This HTML forms does send the request, and the Google authentication works :

```
<form action="/auth/google" method="get">
    <button type="submit">
        Login with google
    </button>
</form>
```

However, the content of the response (JSON) is displayed in the browser, like an HTML page, and replaces the current page, for some reason.
If I prevent the form from submitting (i.e. `e.preventDefault()`), nothing happens at all. I don't know how to just catch the JSON.

So I'm trying to make the same call using Ajax

```
<button type="submit" id="btnGoogle">
    Login with google
</button>

<script>

    $('#btnGoogle').click( (e) => {

        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url :"/auth/google",
                dataType : "json",
                crossDomain : true, // no effect
                headers : {
                    // Tried many headers, no effect
                }
            })
            .success( (data) => {
                console.log("Success!", data))
            })
            .error( (err) => {
                console.error(err.statusText);
            })
        });

    </script>
```

but I get a cross-domain error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_ur…d=178168129307-5g50gah2he0gjjl2or73a1va8ha66s24.apps.googleusercontent.com.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

On the Node/Express server :

```
app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read']
    }));
```

How come the HTML form, that reaches the very same server route with the same parameters, makes it,but the Ajax call doesn't?

**Edit**

I have found a workaround by installing the [CORS extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US), so... Yeah, it kind of works, but why does the Ajax call need this, whereas a regular HTML form doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

**re: why does the Ajax call need this, whereas a regular HTML form doesn't":**

Your basic `ajax` calls cannot process server redirects at all, so cannot handle the redirect from Google's OAuth system.

To avoid the problem for all OAuth providers I had to ensure that the login links were not handled by Ajax and allowed the browser to handle any redirects.

Using an `iframe` to handle the external login and subsequent redirects would be another option if you want it to appear to be a SPA.

Comment: Thanks, it is an element of response and it helps, but doesn't actually solve the problem. I still can't figure out how to get a JSON (JWT) back from a Google button without reloading the entire page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get that last comment?

Comment: @JeremyThille: Sorry wrong interpretation of the payload you wanted. Out of interest, what is your server technology?

Comment: I'm using NodeJS/Express and PassportJS (there's a bit of server code in the question)